# Cedar vs spruce vs larch for building canoe

Tags: wood-species

Among my future woodworking plans is to build a wood and canvas canoe. I have more or less grown up in one and I participated in building one a long time ago so I think I know what I am up to.

When looking into descriptions (mostly from US or Canada), I see the preferred materials are ash and cedar. Ash for the "ribs" going across and cedar for the parts running the length of the canoe. It must be relatively bendable but also able to withstand being wet. My problem is that in Norway where I live, it is more or less impossible to get hold of cedar. Spruce on the other hand is easy to find. Does anyone have any experience on the behavior of spruce as a replacement for cedar for this type of work? I may be able to get hold of larch, that should be pretty good in water, but my little experience with larch says that it is relatively brittle.

From what I read, it may seem that spruce in many ways is a better wood for this use, but cedar is more water resistant.

Comment: The biggest positive of cedar is it is so light vs other woods, Larch is pretty dense, so your canoe would be quite a bit heavier, I would guess that spruce (without knots) would be a decent replacement, other than spruce tends to have a lot of pitch.

Comment: A source for what woods are preferred is "old town" in Maine ,US. They have been making wood canoes forever and were helpful when I contacted them about my canoe. Mine contained about 6 different woods. Unfortunately , I put it out of misery after over 110 years.

Comment: Good points @bowlturner! I was thinking about getting mountain spruce which is more solid and dense, but also more 'knotty'

Comment: Spruce would be an excellent alternative to cedar Morten as it's famous for how stiff it is per unit weight. Knots would be a problem however if the planned source subspecies is knotty the actual yield of usable strips from your starting material could be low, possibly really really low (less than half). You're going to want to be very careful about going down that route, will you be buying in person so you can select for the least knotty boards?

Comment: Re. the water resistance, I'm not sure how reliable that info is. The American 'cedars' (they're not real cedars, they were named this because they smell the same) are *decay resistant* because of the chemical(s) responsible for the characteristic odour, which could be improperly referred to as being resistant to water, which is misleading. Anyway, here in Europe where we don't have faux cedars what woods were traditionally used in building lightweight boats? That's possibly the place to start here and since you come from somewhere with a Viking heritage there should be some good info locally.